# Conda env - Adding an Encrypted Variable

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

I'm following documentation [here](https://anaconda-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/work-with-variables.html#adding-a-variable-with-a-default-value) to add an **encrypted** variable in my miniconda environment to hide a username and password.

my conda env name is selenium_env

I've tried the following 1.) inside the project_repo and 2.) inside \miniconda3\envs\selenium_env, while having selenium_env activated.

```
# documentation syntax
anaconda-project add-variable --default=default_value VARIABLE

# iterations i've tried
selenium_env add-variable --default=my_email USERNAME
anaconda-project add-variable --default=my_email USERNAME
```

Error I get:
[image]

Also, after reading "[Encrypted variable values are kept in the system keychain...](https://anaconda-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/work-with-variables.html#:%7E:text=encrypted%20variable%20values%20are%20kept%20in%20the%20system%20keychain)", I installed [keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) though I suspect the documentation means a different keyring?
Further, the documentation states that "Anaconda Project sets some environment variables automatically: PROJECT_DIR, CONDA_ENV_PATH, PATH..." though I see nothing after running `conda env config vars list`

I did have success setting env variables using [this conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables) but they are not encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have [anaconda-project](https://anaconda-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) installed in my miniconda install.